# Use the mask Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, mask

I have a phone mask. More precisely, an error instead of a mask.
I really can't figure out why the error occurs because it is completely uninformative!!!

[image]

```html
<template>
  <input type="text" v-model="value" v-mask="'#-#-#'" />
</template>

<script>
import { ref, defineComponent } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const value = ref("");

    return { value };
  },
  watch: {
    value(n) {
      this.$emit("input", n);
    },
  },
});
</script>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-resonance-dyl63c?file=/src/App.vue

If you remove the `v-mask` directive, then everything works as it should. How can I solve the error??

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to register it locally, it should work :

```html
<template>
  <input type="text" v-model="value" v-maska="'#-#-#'" />
</template>

<script>
import { ref, defineComponent } from "vue";
import { maska } from "maska";
export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const value = ref("");

    return { value };
  },
  directives: { maska },
  watch: {
    value(n) {
      this.$emit("input", n);
    },
  },
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

- in your main.js instead `app.directive("v-mask", maska)` go with `app.use(maska)`
- in phone.vue instead `v-mask="'#-#-#'"` go with `v-maska="'#-#-#'"`

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-sun-v52dvk?file=/src/components/phone.vue:48-65)